# Filling NA based on match from other column

Tags: pandas, matching, fillna

Hi I am attempting to fill NAs of one column based on the unique value of another column.

Here is an example of the df I am working with:

| CompanyID | CompanyName |
| --- | --- |
| 34 | Company1 |
| NaN | Company1 |
| NaN | Company1 |
| 57 | Company2 |
| 57 | Company2 |
| NaN | Company2 |
| 63 | Company3 |
| 63 | Company3 |
| NaN | Company3 |
| NaN | Company3 |

My desired output:

| CompanyID | CompanyName |
| --- | --- |
| 34 | Company1 |
| 34 | Company1 |
| 34 | Company1 |
| 57 | Company2 |
| 57 | Company2 |
| 57 | Company2 |
| 63 | Company3 |
| 63 | Company3 |
| 63 | Company3 |
| 63 | Company3 |

How can I fill these NAs correctly and efficiently based off of the CompanyName? Usually at least 1 row has the CompanyID provided. Thanks!

Comment: `df.groupby('CompanyName')['CompanyID'].ffill()`

Comment: Thank you @mozway !